# Embed text files written with markdown syntax in another RMarkdown file

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, knitr

I know this seems to be a question already answered in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29257985/r-markdown-how-do-i-show-file-contents).

However, I am going to try to explain my situation clearly.

1. I am writing 3 separate documents using RStudio and RMarkdown. In fact, I am not including any chunks, so it might be purely Markdown syntax.
2. These three documents (`.Rmd`) share some sections, which are identical in the three of them.
3. There are other sections that are different among them.

In order **to write efficiently**, I would like to write the common sections using Markdown syntax in separate files from the three documents I mentioned.

In this way, I would like to include and link those common sections in the three documents (in their respective places).

In this regard, I would like `knitr`, when converting to HTML PDF or DOCX, to take into consideration the syntax of the separate and common sections. I mean, **if there are subheadings, bold, italics, etc, to be correctly identified and converted**.

Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways to do this. Here the first two that came to my mind:

## Using `readLines`:

This is basically the approach from the [question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29264573/2706569), but you have to add the [chunk option `results="asis"`](https://yihui.org/knitr/options/#text-results):

````
```{r results="asis"}
cat(readLines('somefile.txt'), sep = '\n')
```
````

## Using `read_chunk`:

You can also [read multiple code chunks from an external script](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/read-chunk.html) and then use the `asis` engine to display the chunks you refer to with `ref.label`:

**Your  RMD file:**

````
```{r}
knitr::read_chunk("mychunks.R")
```

```{asis, ref.label="firstchunk"}
```

```{asis, ref.label="secondchunk"}
```
````

**File *mychunks.R*:**

```
## ---- firstchunk

Text

# Header

Text

## ---- secondchunk

Text2

# Header2

Text2
```